# repeat the function if element not found

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script that will notify you if someone gets inline on Whatsapp web and I have this script:

```
function addZero(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}

function onlineCheck() {
    var y = document.querySelector('[title="online"]');
    var d = new Date();
    if (y == null) {
      // I want it to repeat onlineCheck() after 1 second
    } else {
        if (y.innerText === 'online') {
            new Notification("contact is online");
            console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) 
            + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) 
            + " " + "Notification sent");
        }
   }
}
```

and I want to replace *// I don't know what to put here*  with something that will run the function `onlineCheck()`

how should I do that

I first had this script:

```
var onlineCheck1 = window.setInterval(function(){ 
    var x = document.querySelector('[title="online"]'); 
    var name = $('#main>header>div.chat-body>div.chat-main>.chat-title>span').text()
    var d = new Date();
    if (x == null) {
        console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) 
        + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) 
        + " " + name + " " + "was" + " " + "offline");
    } else {
        if (x.innerText === "online") {
            console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) 
            + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) 
            + " " + name + " " + "was" + " " + "////online///");
    } else {
        console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) 
        + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) 
        + " " + name + " " + "was" + " " + "offline");
    }
} ,1000);
```

but I want it to not do any thing with console log I just want it to repeat itself till it finds the element with the title="online"

Note: I'm using chrome's console to run the script and you can try it yourself if you want.

Comment: You should just be able to call the function itself again.

Comment: Simply call the function with function name.

Comment: just place `onlineCheck()` and the function itself will be called again. This it's called **recursion** and you can find a lot of good articles about it on the web. However, you must be careful to prevent any function to call itself infinitely: just be sure there is always a condition that prevent the call when some requirement is fullfilled.

Comment: Even though the three comments above provide a simple solution, recommending recursion, I think there still needs to be a way to escape out, to avoid infinite loops if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Joe Absolutely correct. Calling `onlineChck()` again may end up in an endless loop, if `document.querySelector('[title="online"]')` is not being created to fulfill the condition.

Comment: @Joe I agree. I wanted to get more in depth, and recommend the response and reaction as a callback. I just thought of the quickest response to put out there.  Actually ran it in fiddle around the same time to see an infinite loop

Comment: How are you calling onlineCheck function then?

Comment: @GangadharJannu Jannu just put  the script in chrome's console and hit enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the function itself. This is called *Recursion*. You must be careful to prevent `onlineCheck()`calls itself infinitely

```
function onlineCheck() 
{
    var y = document.querySelector('[title="online"]');
    var d = new Date();

    if (y == null) 
    {
        onlineCheck();
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (y.innerText === 'online') 
        {
            new Notification("contact is online");
            console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) + " " + "Notification sent");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there still needs to be a way to escape out, to avoid infinite loops if something goes wrong.

Comment: "*You must be careful*" isn't really helpful. If you make this function recurse directly, nothing else can run at the same time and update the page, and updating the page is the only thing that would make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the function as below

```
function onlineCheck() {
    var y = document.querySelector('[title="online"]');
    var d = new Date();
    if (y == null) {
      onlineCheck();
    } else {
      if (y.innerText === 'online') {
       new Notification("contact is online");
       console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) + " " + "Notification sent");
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think there still needs to be a way to escape out, to avoid infinite loops if something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You need `recursion` technique.

While using this technique, the `recursive function` should need a `termination condition` to end the process (otherwise the process will infinitely iterates  which will eventually cause `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error)

```
function onlineCheck() {
var y = document.querySelector('[title="online"]');
var d = new Date();
if (y == null) {
  // Be sure to add a termination condition
  onlineCheck()
} else {
  if (y.innerText === 'online') {
   new Notification("contact is online");
   console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) + " " + "Notification sent");
}
}
}
```

Comment: `y != null` is the termination condition.

Comment: @melpomene Who knows what is termination condition. the OP didn't mention about it

Comment: Why downvote?. if y!=null is the termination condition he doesn't need to call the function again

Comment: I know what it is because it's right there in the code.

Comment: We can't say what is there in OP mind. All we do is giving suggestions

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know what you mean with termination condition
what my script does is search for the element with the title="online" and if it doesn't exist (if the person is offline or turned off his last seen)  I want it to try again till it finds it and notify me. Note: this is for whatsapp web and i'm running the script with chome's console .

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, you could just call the function directly: `onlineCheck();`. However, the loop condition (`document.querySelector('[title="online"]') != null`) won't have changed if you do that, so it'll go into an infinite loop/recursion.

Here's another way:

```
function onlineCheck() {
    var y = document.querySelector('[title="online"]');
    var d = new Date();
    if (y == null) {
        setTimeout(onlineCheck, 10);
    } else {
        if (y.innerText === 'online') {
            new Notification("contact is online");
            console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + "|" + addZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getSeconds()) + " " + "Notification sent");
        }
    }
}
```

This re-schedules `onlineCheck` to be called after 10 milliseconds, giving the page a chance to update before checking again. You may want to increase this number to, say, `1000`; this way it'll check once every second instead of spinning in place, going "*are we done yet? how about now? how about now? and now? now? now?*".

Comment: y != null is the termination condition.

Comment: your solution sounds the best except it's not working for some reason, note: i'm using chrome's console to run the script.

Comment: @GangadharJannu That's what I said, yes. What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: @ELIASYOUSSEF Ah. I'm sorry, I don't use Chrome and I don't know what the limitations of its console are or how it implements timers.

Comment: You said the same however you also didn't mention the termination condition.

Comment: @GangadharJannu Yes. Why does it have to be mentioned explicitly? I also didn't mention that the local variables are called `y` and `d`, or that the function takes no arguments. What is your point?

Comment: What's the point? whatever we have answered is similar, you did mention that y!=null for me and you didn't mention it for your answer. That is what I'm trying say

Comment: @GangadharJannu Because your answer says `// Be sure to add a termination condition` right after the termination check, `if (y == null)`. Which was there from the beginning, so why add another one? It looks like you don't understand the structure of the code. (It's also not helpful to say "*here's some broken code; you need to add a termination condition*" without explaining what that is or how you'd do that.)

Comment: How can you say that y!=null / y==null is a termination condition. Did he mention?. Who knows, user wants to check the element innerText==online or innerText==offline. What I did was suggesting the user to add a termination condition which is appropriate for him. We can't exactly say what he was trying to do unless he explicitly says something. In addition OP didn't clearly mention the requirement, so I've given overview of recursion and termination condition